# How to install sdks for android inside eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

The other day on a different machine i was able to install many android sdk versions all at once using something in eclipse. I cannot remember how I did this and was wondering if anyone might know how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: i have found the answer, sorry. Please feel free to close

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the directions given at http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html, and then use the SDK manager to select, download and install whichever SDK(s) you need.